# download a file periodically from FTP in linux

Tags: linux, ftp, download

I wish to write a cron or setup a software to periodically download a file every specific day of a week from a FTP server.
I need a software like IDM which opens multi thread connections and increase the download speed significantly.
Because of that I prefer to use an application.

I already tried uGet and flareget on Ubuntu but they don't contain any feature to run the same download every day of a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a console application like axel to get this work.
If you have to rename the download you should write a little bash script to complete the task.
Finally call the script every ... by cron.

Hennes

Comment: Thank you I finally used AXEL and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that in Flareget. In scheduler you have two options one time and periodic. In periodic you can set week day and time. But file needs to be added to custom queue again after each download.